# Cannot find modules that have been installed locally by NPM

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, package.json

I am working on a tool and I have installed some modules locally through NPM, and I get errors when I try to require these modules through NodeJS. I am working in Windows 10, I have already tried setting up NODE_PATH etc.

Below is the structure of my files:

```
->project  
---->node_modules  
---->src  
-------->css  
-------->js  
----------->index.js  
---->package.json  
---->index.html
```

I populate the index.html by using index.js etc.
Below is the code of my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "bip39",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A tool for converting BIP39 mnemonic phrases to addresses and private keys.",
  "directories": {
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bip39": "^2.6.0",
    "bigi": "^1.4.2",
    "create-hmac": "^1.1.7",
    "nem-sdk": "^1.6.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/PavlosTze/bip39.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/PavlosTze/bip39/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/PavlosTze/bip39#readme"
}
```

Below is my require() code:

```
var createHmac = require("create-hmac");
var BigInteger = require("bigi");
const bip39 = require("bip39");
const nem = require("nem-sdk").default;
```

I have done the following steps on NPM:
1) npm init
2) npm install bip39
3) npm install nem-sdk
4) npm install bigi
5) npm install create-hmac

All these files are inside the `node_modules`, but still, whenever I run the code in the browser I get an 'Error: Cannot find module "bip39"', etc. for all modules.

EDIT: On another directory that I have cloned the same tool, before I merged it with another one, I get no error and everything works correctly, including the require(). etc. Do you need any of those files as well?

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Well Node doesn't run in the browser so I feel a few details are missing... one thing you can do if you already have your package.json is to delete the node_modules and run `node install` and it will re-build that folder.

Comment: "On another directory that I have cloned the same tool, before I merged it with another one, I get no error and everything works correctly"... so what's the difference between those directories?

Comment: @illcrx The other tool runs in a browser page as well (as it is a JS tool hosted in an HTML page). I did a re-build, same error occurs.

Comment: @eis The package.json file, and the fact that the tool that works correctly gets compiled with gulp, whereas that gets compiled with Python. To make it more clear, the tool that works correct is just a "feature", and the one that doesn't work and gets me the "cannot find module" error, is a big program, that worked correctly, and now that feature integrated to that.

Comment: The code is in my github as well, in the first post at the package.json is a link to my github repo where you can find the full code.

Comment: How do you start your project? I see that in your github project that you have some compile Python script that just adds your scripts to the HTML file, but what do you use to compile your NPM dependencies?

Comment: @5ar Maybe that's my mistake, I don't know exactly what do you mean to be honest. I just do "python compile.py" and I run the standalone HTML file that gets created. Nothing more than that. Can you please elaborate more how/what to do to compile my NPM dependencies? Maybe in a post as it might solve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```